# Analytics unable to get all reports

Tags: community, rest-api, analytics

I am using the end point below to retrieve all available reports to my profile.

https://eu9.salesforce.com/services/data/v41.0/analytics/reports

However I am only able to get the following, which is in My Personal Custom Reports.

```
[
    {
        "describeUrl": "/services/data/v41.0/analytics/reports/00O0X000004AA/describe",
        "fieldsUrl": "/services/data/v41.0/analytics/reports/00O0X000004AA/fields",
        "id": "00O0X000004AA",
        "instancesUrl": "/services/data/v41.0/analytics/reports/00O0X000004AA/instances",
        "name": "v1",
        "url": "/services/data/v41.0/analytics/reports/00O0X000004AA"
    }
]
```

Can someone please tell if I am doing anything wrongly? I want to get all reports which I have rights to.